# go/0 Undefined procedure save/1

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

swi-prolog 5.10.2

I have typed this prolog program in. However, when I run option a I get the following error.

```
go/0 Undefined Procedure save/1
```

I am sure that save is a proper keyword predicate, and the path to the file does exist as well. Not sure where I am going wrong here.

```
What does the /0 /1 mean in go and save?
```

Source code

```
/* Shopping list */

go:-reconsult('~/projects/prolog/chap7/shopping.pl'),
    write('a: See list'), nl,
    write('b: Add to list'), nl,
    write('c: Delete from list'), nl,
    read(Choice),
    choice(Choice),
    save('~/projects/prolog/chap7/shopping.pl').

/*
  facts for shopping
*/
item(potatoes).
item(bread).
item(coffee).

/*
  Rules for shopping list
*/
choice(a):-listing(item), nl.
choice(b):-write('Enter an item: '),
        read(Item),
        assert(item(Item)).
choice(c):-write('Item to delete: '),
        read(Item),
        retract(item(Item)).
choice(_):-write('Incorrect entry.'), nl.
```

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message states that the predicate `go/0` you defined makes use of a predicate `save/1` that the system does not recognize and label as an undefined procedure. Predicates are usually identified by a *predicate indicator* in the form `name/arity`, where name is the name of the predicate, represented as an atom, and arity is a number representing how many parameters the predicate has been defined accepting: so, for example, `go/0` is the identifier for the predicate `go`, with no parameters, defined in your program; and `save/1` is the identifier for the predicate `save`, with one parameter, that you are trying to invoke but the system is unable to find. When a predicate has been defined through two or more overloaded versions, e.g. with a different arity for each definition, it may be referred by enclosing each arity between brackets, separated with a comma, e.g. `p/[1,2]`. Predicates are sometimes called procedures, the two terms being roughly equivalent.

As it's possible to see in [older SWI-Prolog manuals](http://euclid.barry.edu/~segami/Manual/sec-2.9.html) (the link refers to version 2.9) `save/1` indeed used to be defined in the standard library and generally available on those systems. Even in those old systems, it was suggested to use `save_program/[1,2]` to create a new program instead of `save/1`, which was said to be exploited for debug purposes only. However, in modern SWI-Prolog systems, nor `save/1` neither `save_program/[1,2]` are available. While it seems that there is no equivalent predicate for `save/1`, the role of `save_program/[1,2]` has been taken by `qsave_program/[1,2]`, which you can read about [in the latest version of the manual](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%281,%2710%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/runtime.html%27%29%29). Be sure to read also about [its limitations](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%2710.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/qsavelimits.html%27%29%29), just in case you'd want to expand your program way beyond the simple snippet you posted here.

Having never used that kind of procedures, I must assume you know what you are doing. However, noticing the `reconsult/1` call at the beginning of your program that uses the same file saved by `save/1` later, I beg you to become aware that there's a difference between a bunch of Prolog predicates in a text file, i.e. the format that `reconsult/1` can read and understand, and the half-text half-binary format that at least `qsave_program` (but I maintain `save` and `save_program` too) uses to write the program on disk. Since, by reading your code, it seems you may be interested in storing the shopping list's items, as an aside note I would like to add that you may save predicates of interest in a plain text file by using a combination of `listing/1` with [I/O procedures](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.15%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/IO.html%27%29%29) such as `open/3`, `set_output/1`, `current_output/1`, and the like.

Comment: The prolog book I was reading was published in 1994. So maybe out of date. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You write: "Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official 
sources". If you desired a first hand feedback, you should post your 
question on the SWI mailing list:

[SWI-Prolog 5.11.29, Mailing list](http://www.swi-prolog.org/Mailinglist.html)

Usually you have the main author of SWI prolog in the loop and also 
many contributors.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you're getting the error, since I'm not very familiar with SWI Prolog, but the /1 /0 means the number of arguments in the predicate. In this case, you're invoking save with 1 argument, hence, save/1.

Also, have you tried using the predicate save_program/1? As far as I can tell, save should only be used for debug (from http://euclid.barry.edu/~segami/Manual/sec-2.9.html).

In the examples I saw, the save/save_program predicate was always called without quotes or a file extension. I got the impression that the language handled that part for you.
Like: save(filename), instead of save('filename.pl').